# Roblox API Discord Embed If statement Issue

Tags: python, discord, embed, roblox

```py
main_group_id = 14683506  
army_group_id = 15263473
enemy_group_id = 6521883

# Get main_group_rank (THIS WORKS!)

for group_data in user_groups_data.get("data", []):
    if group_data.get("group", {}).get("id") == main_group_id:
        rank_id = group_data.get("role", {}).get("rank")

# Fetch group roles to find the rank name
        group_api_url = f"https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/{main_group_id}/roles"
        group_response = requests.get(group_api_url)
        if group_response.status_code == 200:
            group_info = group_response.json()
            main_group_rank = None

            for role_data in group_info.get("roles", []):
                if role_data.get("rank") == rank_id:
                    main_group_rank = role_data.get("name")
                    break

            if main_group_rank is not None:
                print(f"User Rank: {main_group_rank}")
            else:
                print("Rank name not found.")
    else:
        main_group_rank = None

army_group_rank = None   # WORKS ALSO
for group_data in user_groups_data.get("data", []):
    if group_data.get("group", {}).get("id") == army_group_id:
        rank_id = group_data.get("role", {}).get("rank")
        print("Army in user")
        # Fetch group roles to find the rank name
        group_api_url = f"https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/{army_group_id}/roles"
        group_response = requests.get(group_api_url)
        if group_response.status_code == 200:
            group_info = group_response.json()
            print("Army 200")
            for role_data in group_info.get("roles", []):
                if role_data.get("rank") == rank_id:
                    army_group_rank = role_data.get("name")
                    print("Army Yes")
                    break

            if army_group_rank is not None:
                print(f"Army Rank: {army_group_rank}")
            else:
                print("Rank name not found.")
    else:
        army_group_rank = None

if main_group_rank:
    print("Adding Main Rank field")
    embed.add_field(name='Main Rank', value=main_group_rank, inline=False) # THIS WORKS!!!!
else:
    print("Main Rank is None")

if army_group_rank:
    print("Adding Army Rank field")
    embed.add_field(name='Army Rank', value=army_group_rank, inline=False) # THIS DOES NOT WORK BECAUSE [1]
else:
    print("Army Rank is None")

if enemy_group_rank:
    print("Adding Enemy Rank field")
    embed.add_field(name="Enemy Rank", value=enemy_group_rank, inline=False)
else:
    print("Enemy Rank is None")
```

[1]
outputs:
I am printing out both, main rank and army rank in the fetch functions. They both are not None. But when I try to access army rank in the embed it says its None. Why is that and how do I fix this?

Command Output:

**User Rank: Imperial Development Office**

Army in user

Army 200

Army Yes

**Army Rank: Imperial Chancellery**

User information updated successfully!

User information updated in the database.

Adding Main Rank field

***Army Rank is None***

Enemy Rank is None

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out a similar script myself, which seemed to work as expected. Are you sure the indentation isn't wrong?

It might be because of the last else statement somehow being invalidated and instead being a truthy statement, where army_group_rank will always be set to after, no matter the previous actions.

Have you tried using breakpoints to debug which flow your code goes through?

Comment: Yup, the indentation was just the same as for main_group_rank

Comment: @Karo does that mean your issue is solved now?

Comment: sadly not, i meant that the indentation was not the problem :/

Comment: Is what you posted the whole script, or did you leave out something inbetween the part where the embed is added and the rank is allocated?

Comment: It is indeed not the whole code its a minimum working code example, i can answer with the whole code if that helps

Comment: It might be more useful, as the code that is posted as-is, should work as expected.